# ERROR MicroBatchExecution: When integrating Kafka with pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to send data to pySpark but it is giving me this error:
ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = d3a1ed30-d223-4da4-9052-189b103afca8, runId = 70bfaa84-15c9-4c8b-9058-0f9a04ee4dd0] terminated with error
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'

Producer

```
import tweepy
import json
import time
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import twitterauth as auth
import utils

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=["localhost:9092"], value_serializer=utils.json_serializer)

class twitterStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_connect(self):
        print("Twitter Client Connected")

    def on_tweet(self, raw_data):
        if raw_data.referenced_tweets == None:
            producer.send(topic="registered_user", value=raw_data.text) 
            print("Producer Running")          
            

    def on_error(self):
        self.disconnect()

    def adding_rules(self, keywords):
        for terms in keywords:
            self.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule(terms))
    


    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stream = twitterStream(bearer_token=auth.bearer_token)
    stream_terms = ['bitcoin','luna','etherum']
    stream.adding_rules(stream_terms)
    stream.filter(tweet_fields=['referenced_tweets'])
```

pySpark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

import findspark

import json
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = f'--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0 pyspark-shell'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    findspark.init()

   # spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Kafka Pyspark Streaming Learning").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    
    sc = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]") \
                    .appName('SparkByExamples.com') \
                    .getOrCreate()


    df = sc \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
        .option("startingoffsets","latest") \
        .option("subscribe", "registered_user") \
        .load()
    
    query = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
    
    query = df.writeStream.format("console").start()
    import time
    time.sleep(10) # sleep 10 seconds
    query.stop()
```

Hadoop Version: 3.3.0
Spark and PySpark version: 3.3.0
Scala Version: 2.12.15

I have tried everything for the last 8 hours still no luck. Could anyone help?

StackTrace:
[image]

When I run df.printSchema() there is no error and this is the output:
[image]

Comment: Probably you need to use different name for holding the converted fields ? e.g. castDf = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") query = castDf .writeStream.format("console").start()

Comment: Try searching how to fix `Unable to load native-hadoop library`  warning message for Windows

Comment: @BrahmanandSingh solution solved it. But, now I want to know why? The fix was so simple, what was the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Dataframes are imutable, so when you casted it you need to make it into another dataframe.

Comment: @BernardJoshua: Posted the updates as answer in order to get it viewed as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use different name for holding the converted fields as the Dataframe is immutable , your initial dataframe is named df and it has certain schema, when you are casting the fields to string you need to have a seperate name.

```
castDf = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") 

query = castDf .writeStream...
```